# Dualsense controller not functioning properly in Ubuntu 20.04 / Linux 5.15.1

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kernel

I have recently bought a Dualsense controller for use with my computer. I did this because there is [in-kernel (official) support] present for it. I updated my Ubuntu to the latest stable kernel release (5.15.1) using `mainline`, as the currently running kernel was 5.13 and thus too low for the in-kernel driver to be supported.

Pairing with it did not work, and it was not recognized at all, so I plugged it in with a USB cable (Which is non-ideal but I hoped would help me to resolve any problems with it). It "worked", and currently I have tried using it with Steam, which seemed to recognize it as a Dualshock 4 controller, however the right analog stick is seemingly not functioning properly, and the light is unable to be set.

In short, the problems are:

- Dualsense right analog stick is non functional
- Dualsense light bar is unable to be set by Steam

Personally, I'm not even sure how to *start* debugging this. Dmesg output gives:

```
[ 2028.118785] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 2028.268870] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=0ce6, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 2028.268879] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 2028.268883] usb 2-2: Product: Wireless Controller
[ 2028.268886] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Sony Interactive Entertainment
[ 2028.310395] playstation 0003:054C:0CE6.0003: hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Gamepad [Sony Interactive Entertainment Wireless Controller] on usb-0000:06:00.3-2/input3
[ 2028.367847] input: Sony Interactive Entertainment Wireless Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.3/0003:054C:0CE6.0003/input/input24
[ 2028.368112] input: Sony Interactive Entertainment Wireless Controller Motion Sensors as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.3/0003:054C:0CE6.0003/input/input25
[ 2028.368239] input: Sony Interactive Entertainment Wireless Controller Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb2/2-2/2-2:1.3/0003:054C:0CE6.0003/input/input26
[ 2028.369126] playstation 0003:054C:0CE6.0003: Registered DualSense controller hw_version=0x00000413 fw_version=0x01020014
[ 2030.471758] input: Microsoft X-Box 360 pad as /devices/virtual/input/input27
```

so it *seems* to be recognized.

I'm asking specifically either:

- **What are the solutions to these issues?**
- **How do I start resolving these issues on my own? Where do I start?**

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to this, but you could try installing the Ubuntu LTS enablement (also called HWE or Hardware Enablement) stacks using:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

I used this to install kernel 5.15.0-84-generic in my Ubuntu 20.04.6 Machine and my DualSense started working perfectly.

I did try to install the newer kernels via Mainline Kernels but I always dependency errors when installing the kernel headers, which ended up messing with my Nvidia Drivers. The HWE option left my Nvidia drivers working.

For more information in HWE check out [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).